# Flutter iOS: CCLocationManager did fail with Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

Tags: ios, flutter, core-location, permission-denied

Flutter app that uses `google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6`, `location: ^4.3.0`  and `permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2` produces iOS error in the title on the next launch or lock/unlock screen, when location permissions is denied or set to never.

Permission is asked not on the first screen but on the third. But error keep showing event on start up.

This is how location permission is asked

```
 Future<void> _initGeolocation() async {
bool serviceEnabled;

serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();

if (!serviceEnabled) {
  return;
}

_permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied ||
    _permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.deniedForever) {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await _showLocationInfoPopup();
  } else {
    await _showLocationSettingsPopup();
  }

  _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();

  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}

final coordinates = await _location.getLocation();

if (coordinates != null) {
  _initialUserPosition =
      LatLng(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude);
}

_userPositionSubscription = _location.onLocationChanged
    .listen((event) => _updateUserLocation(event));
return;
```

}

This is Info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>1</string>
```

This is Podfile

```
## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
      'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
```